# ScalaFX can't find a css resource file

Tags: scala, user-interface, javafx, scalafx

I am creating a GUI for my app, and I want to style it. To add css to a scene, I use the following code:

```scala
val scene = new Scene(parent = root) {     
    stylesheets.add(getClass.getResource("a.css").toExternalForm)
}
```

The directory structure is as follows:
[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WI7yX.png),
with the source code file in the /scala folder and a.css file in the /resources folder.

However, when I try to load the file, I get an error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because the return value of "java.lang.Class.getResource(String)" is null`.

My sbt file contains the following text:

```
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "3.3.1"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "My project"
  )

libraryDependencies += "org.scalafx" % "scalafx_3" % "20.0.0-R31"
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" %% "toolkit" % "0.1.7"
```

I have also tried providing absolute path, absolute path prepended with a '/' or a '\' (I am using Windows), and relative paths starting from /src, /main, and /resources folders; nothing worked.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check the build folder and make sure the CSS file is being deployed to the same place as the class file. You appear to be using the default package (no explicit package name), which is not really recommended, for both.

Comment: Assuming that Scala uses the same packaging schema that Java does, I would expect the code as written to look for the file in a directory under resources that matches the package that the class in is.  So if this code is from com.example.myapp.SomeClass.scala, then the file would be in /resources/com/example/myapp/a.css